# Weird behaviour of \@title in hyperref and tikzposter

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, tikzposter

When I use `hyperref` to set the pdf properties (title, author, keywords), `\@title` shows up with a `1` in the front. Within the title on the document and everywhere else, it is normal (without the 1). This also only happens to `\@title` and not for any other command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{\renewcommand\@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\@subtitle{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\title{test title}\let\Title\@title%
\subtitle{test subtitle}\let\Subtitle\@subtitle%
\author{test author}\let\Author\@author%
\makeatother

% todo fill pdf
\usepackage[pdftex,
            unicode,
            ]{hyperref}

\def\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title~\@subtitle},pdfsubject={\@title~\@subtitle},pdfauthor={\@author}}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Results in: `1test title test subtitle` (I observed this behavior in various PDF viewers)
[image: Properties of pdf document]

Why?

Comment: if you do `\show\@title` you will get `\scalebox {\TP@titletextscale }{test title}.`. You can also see in the log the warning from hyperref that it removed the `\scalebox`. The scale factor remains and gives the 1. That means the `\@title` definition from the class is not really usable in the pdf metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\renewcommand\title{\renewcommand\@title}` does the trick!